# My whole is not my whole, but to post this riddle seems like my whole

Tags: word, wordplay, affix-riddle

> My prefix is my prefix
> My suffix is my suffix
> My infix is my infix
> My whole is not my whole, but to post this riddle seems like my whole.

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is

> risky

My prefix is my prefix

> **risk** is the prefix of *risky mysteries*

My suffix is my suffix

> **y** is the suffix of "my".

My infix is my infix

> The infix just **is** (or perhaps another appropriately chosen string from *risky mysteries*)

My whole is not my whole, but to post this riddle seems like my whole.

> **risky** is not the same as *risky mysteries* but to post a riddle whose answer is just the first part of your username seems **risky**.

Comment: I wouldn't use a username as the answer to a riddle, as usernames can be changed at anytime.

Comment: @riskymysteries It certainly would be a risky thing to do.  :D